# Why does non-asan bulid not crash?

Tags: crash, address-sanitizer

I witnessed a crash in the Asan compilation environment.

However, in a normal compilation environment, there is no crash.

What makes the difference?

Is this safe?

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say without a reprocase e.g. this may be result of incorrect compilation flags. Asan should give you detailed message and backtrace on crash which you could use to understand what went wrong (or you could just run program in gdb).

Comment: @yugr So, if you do not get a crash in a binary generated from a regular compilation
not exploitable?

Comment: It depends, it may still be exploitable. My understanding is the crash you get is due to invalid setup but you did not provide any details so it's hard to say.